# How do I remove all programs connected to Wine and Wine with one command?

Tags: 10.04, wine

I want to remove all programs associated to Wine and Wine itself in one command, can it be done? The whole point of this question is that I don't want to find any files connected to wine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## WARNING! DOING THIS WILL DESTROY DATA

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
rm -rf ~/.wine
```

If you really want it to be one command, replace the newline between the two lines with `&&`

That will remove Wine (if you installed it from the repo) and it'll destroy the default installation area for applications.

#### Things it won't do:

- It won't remove Wine if you installed it without a package.
- It won't delete things that have been installed to non-standard places.
- It won't delete files that Wine applications have created outside of `~/.wine`
- It won't clean up your menu.
- It won't clean up any file associations you've pointed at Wine apps.
- It won't call you tomorrow morning.

#### Clean up your Menus with Alacarte

Because the above won't remove old program links in your menus, you need to manually remove the Wine applications. Thankfully in recent versions of Wine, all programs are automatically clustered under a "Wine" submenu. We just need to hide or remove this:

1. Right click the Menu button and click Edit Menus
2. Find the Wine portion and either delete it or uncheck it.

Comment: I will add `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove wine dependencies (and also other unnecessary packages).

Comment: ok, that wasn't what I was looking for, if I want to remove it from the menu how do I remove it then?

Comment: Right click the Menu button → Edit Menus → Find the Wine portion and either delete it or uncheck it.

Comment: put that in your answer! :)

Comment: lol @ call you tomorrow morning!

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
rm -rf $HOME/.wine
rm -f $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
```

This would uninstall wine and remove all menus and icons.

Comment: @alvar what are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

I removed wine and associates program using:

Run this in your terminal for removed all wine apps:

```
cd $HOME
rm -rf .wine
```

Run this command to delete from system menu::

```
rm -f $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.{xpm,png}
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/*-x-wine-*.{xpm,png}
```

[Source:](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?s=f696a2d484ece2e2f33471ce92ecfb92&p=1581871&postcount=11)

Answer (score 1):

I typed `sudo apt-get remove wine*` and it worked, it removed wine and all programs, but it also removed ubuntu-desktop. But now everything works thanks!

Comment: The right expression is not `wine*` but `^wine`. (I'm leaving this comment because it seems that somebody run the command you have posted.)

Comment: **I** ran that command, that's why I posted it... @AndreaCorbellini

Comment: [You are not the only one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333546/virtual-box-error-after-reinstallation-of-12-04-64bit)

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @Alaukik works great but as mentioned by Oli in his answer if the `wine` is installed without a package then following answer :

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
rm -rf $HOME/.wine
rm -f $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm -f $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
```

does not do the great job at complete removal of `wine`. So to have an absolute removal  do the following along with above scripts.

```
sudo apt-get purge wine* ; sudo dpkg --purge wine*
```

Cheers!!!