# virtual box error after reinstallation of 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, wine, virtualbox, 64-bit

i was trying to uninstall wine, but the command i got from this site destroyed my ubuntu machine. the command was "sudo apt-get remove wine*" or --purge in place of remove would do same thing. it uninstalled everything. luckly i had everything on an external hdd.

so i reinstalled 12.04 64bit. started up virtual box, made a virtual machine for 12.04 32bit. (was going to test wine apps in it). the installation process was ok. but after reboot of the virtual machine, i get low graphics window at bootup. then i deleted and tried again. same thing.

i gave the virtual machine:
 2 CPU cores
 2GB ram
 128MB video ram
 3d & 2d acceleration.
 16GB HDD.

my ubuntu 64bit machine has:
AMD 4 core
16GB ram
nvidia gtx 650
1TB+

It was working before the melt down. soo im not getting it...
[image]

Comment: Is that error message from the virtual machine or from virtual box itself?

Comment: the wm. its ubuntu giving the message

Comment: Did you get the right driver for your video card after reinstalling Ubuntu on your physical machine?

Comment: thanks for reminding me, but the 310 driver is the current one installed. ill try the older non-experimental one. ill update in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was to go to the device menu then select *Install Guest Additions*.
What it does is downloading an ISO and auto mounting it in the current VM.

Then all I had to do what was running:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Before installing the ISO this command didnt work. So install the ISO first.

Answer (score 1):

First go into the VM's settings and enable 3D acceleration from Display. Then boot the machine and install the `virtualbox-guest-utils` package. After rebooting, the graphics problem should be resolved.

Comment: 3d acceleration is enabled in the display settings for the vm. and the farthest point i get is a CLI login. basicly no gui.

Comment: OK, then try logging in with your username and password, if you get a log in prompt, or you can get to one with <ctrl> - <alt> - <F1> (as long as <ctrl> is not the host key). Then you can install the package with `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`.

Comment: i made the edit and thats what i had to do. just running the install without iso didnt work

Comment: @Alex please, just write an answer using the box below, since what you propose is another solution, so you can get reputation for such.