# "Package 'wine' is not installed, so not removed ... winehq-devel is already the newest version (1.9.24~ubuntu16.04.1)

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

I don't quite understand what is happening. I tried to install wine a couple weeks ago using the instructions on WineHQ to fetch the packages, updates, and install. I attempted to run Terraria.exe through wine, but every time I did, nothing happened. I am able to open winecfg through terminal. Since nothing was happening, I figured my install must've gone wrong so today, I used

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
[sudo] password for Bootin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'wine' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cabextract libmspack0 linux-headers-4.4.0-47 linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic p7zip
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded
```

and subsequently

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommended winehq-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
winehq-devel is already the newest version (1.9.24~ubuntu16.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cabextract libmspack0 linux-headers-4.4.0-47 linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic p7zip
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I am at a loss. I tried to run the program through terminal, and got at least 100 "fixme......state 6" errors
I still have a .wine folder with the nested folders in it. I've also run the terraria server, which opens but immediately closes. I cant find anything in Ubuntu application manager, or anywhere else on my computer, yet I can still access winecfg through terminal. I need to know how I can repair this install, or completely purge it from my computer and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the following command

```
sudo apt-get purge wine* ; sudo dpkg --purge wine*
```

where * represents your installed wine version
i found this really useful on 
[How do I remove all programs connected to Wine and Wine with one command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35010/how-do-i-remove-all-programs-connected-to-wine-and-wine-with-one-command)

Answer (score 0):

In the installation instructions on WineHQ they offer two versions of wine, I don't know why you installed the devel version, as of now its about 6 . releases ahead of the stable stream. https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Follow the other answer and then reinstall with the stable version. I would recommend from now on if you want something to work and will be at a loss if it doesn't don't install the preview or developer builds (alpha beta whatever) because they're for advanced users or developers who may be able to easily fix their problem or not be stopped by atypical behavior. Stable relases are the ones meant to "Just work".